# Why does CodeRush warn me of an Unused Declaration in code?

Tags: c#, coderush

I have this code, which I use all over my applications to save data back to the database.

```
    public bool SaveDemo()
    {
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            using (DataTable dt = DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable("[dbo].[udp_Customers_ups]",
                DataAccess.Parameter(CustomerIdColumn, CustomerId),
                DataAccess.Parameter(CodeColumn, Code),
                DataAccess.Parameter(CompanyColumn, Company),
                DataAccess.Parameter(IsDeletedColumn, IsDeleted),
                DataAccess.Parameter(LastUpdatedColumn, LastUpdated),
                DataAccess.Parameter(UpdatedByColumn, UpdatedBy)))

                success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

The code works as is, which by that I mean it saves the data back to the database. However CodeRush complains about the dt being an Unused Declaration.  And since the Using is (I think) using the dt I would think that the warning is a false positive. So I am left wondering if CodeRush is wrong or if I am missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a using block

Comment: I started using the Using block because I have read that is automatically calls the Dispose() method and was a better practice then doing it without it.

Comment: @WorkSmarter This is not the case - the *declaration* is unused (OP's response is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What CR is trying to say is that in:

```
using (DataTable dt =  DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable ...
```

you are not *using* the declaration of `dt`; the variable remains untouched after.

The refactor button will transform this to

```
using ( DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable ...
```

i.e. it will still be a `using` statement but you won't have a variable to refer to it.

While you're doing that, you can do some Inline Result transformations, yielding:

```
    try
    {
        using (DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable("[dbo].[udp_Customers_ups]",
            DataAccess.Parameter(CustomerIdColumn, CustomerId),
            DataAccess.Parameter(CodeColumn, Code),
            DataAccess.Parameter(CompanyColumn, Company),
            DataAccess.Parameter(IsDeletedColumn, IsDeleted),
            DataAccess.Parameter(LastUpdatedColumn, LastUpdated),
            DataAccess.Parameter(UpdatedByColumn, UpdatedBy)))
            return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I'll let others question whether wrapping calls like this in a `catch` block is a good idea...

Comment: Since you bring up the Try Catch as possibly a bad practice, Let me ask this. If I get rid of it can I assume that a successful using (DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable will allways hit the true and an unsuccessfull one will not? If that is the case I can remove it and still get the results I am trying to get.

Comment: @BukHix Not 100% what you mean. If the `DataAccess....` call throws 1) the Dispose will happen 2) execution will not run any statements after. The one thing you'll need to do is supply a statement to be the body of the using block. Because an empty statement (`;`) will trigger a compiler warning, the next best thing is an empty block:- `{ }`. Can you calrify what you are asking? My complaint re a catch is that you should only catch at top level and log etc. rather than sweeping it under the carpet deep inside your logic

Comment: I think I am going to ask this in a new question because I really want to understand what this code does and don't want to make any assumptions about it.